# Как заставить срабатывать подменю в вертикальном адаптивном меню?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Что имеем: есть [проект](http://martynuk.esy.es/index.html)
с адаптивным вертикальным меню, при уменьшении окна браузера появляется иконка, кликаем по ней, открывается меню. Проблема что не открываются подменю в первом пункте: Литература по дошкольному образованию. Переход на ссылку срабатывает, а вот подменю не открывается. Не могу понять что сделано не так

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sidebar__menu-item > a").click(function() {
    var ul = $(this).next(),
      clone = ul.clone().css({
        "height": "auto"
      }).appendTo(".mobile__menu"),
      height = ul.css("height") === "0px" ? ul[0].scrollHeight + "px" : "0px";
    clone.remove();
    ul.animate({
      "height": height
    });
    return false;
  });
  $('.mobile__menu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
    $('.sidebar__menu-item a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  $('.sidebar__menu-item ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.sidebar__menu-item ul li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.mobile-menu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: $stack-color;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  margin: -5px auto;
}
.mobile-menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: $stack-color;
}
.mobile-menu > ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

.mobile-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: left;
 margin-right: 1px;*/
}
/*Style for menu links*/

.mobile-menu li a {
  display: block;
  min-width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: lighten($stack-color, 5%);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.mobile-menu .sidebar__menu-item > ul {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
}
/*Hover state for top level links*/

.mobile-menu li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: $stack-color;
}
/*Style for dropdown links*/

.mobile-menu li:hover ul a {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

.mobile-menu li:hover .mobile-menu ul a:hover {
  color: #4db3ff;
}
/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

.mobile-menu li ul {
  display: none;
}
/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

.mobile-menu li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}
/*Prevent text wrapping*/

.mobile-menu li ul li a {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.mobile-menu .show-menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2f8db3;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -215px;
  right: 0;
}
.mobile-menu .show-menu span {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
/*Hide checkbox*/

.mobile-menu input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

.mobile-menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #sidebar__menu-list {
  display: block;
}
/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .mobile-menu .lines {
    border-bottom: 15px double #2f8db3;
    border-top: 5px solid #2f8db3;
    content: "";
    height: 5px;
    width: 30px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  .mobile-menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  .mobile-menu li {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  .mobile-menu ul li,
  .mobile-menu li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .mobile-menu .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
.mobile__menu {
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 270px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mobile__menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.mobile__menu > ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
.mobile__menu > ul > li > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  display: block;
  min-width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: lighten($stack-color, 5%);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}
.mobile__menu .sidebar__menu-item > ul {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-menu">
  <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">
    <span>Каталог</span>
    <div class="lines"></div>
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu">
  <ul class="sidebar__menu-list" id="sidebar__menu-list">
    <li class="sidebar__menu-item">
      <a href="catalog.html" class="sidebar__menu-link">Литература по дошкольному образованию</a>
      <ul class="drop">
        <li><a href="#">Английский язык для дошкольников</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Комплексного развитие ребенка</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Математика для дошкольников</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Окружающий мир для дошкольников</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Письмо для дошкольников</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Развитие мышления у дошкольника</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Развитие речи дошкольников</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Русский язык для дошкольников</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar__menu-item">
      <a href="#" class="sidebar__menu-link">Учебники для начальной школы</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar__menu-item">
      <a href="#" class="sidebar__menu-link">Основная школа (5-11) класс</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar__menu-item">
      <a href="#" class="sidebar__menu-link">Иностранные языки</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar__menu-item">
      <a href="#" class="sidebar__menu-link">Дополнительная литература</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar__menu-item">
      <a href="#" class="sidebar__menu-link">ЕГЭ и ГИА</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

```
height = ul.css("height") === "0px" ? ul[0].scrollHeight + "px" : "0px";
```

Как я понял ошибка именно тут т.к. для блока высота всегда выставляется 0px. 
Причина простая - scrollHeight не применимо в Jquery.

Вот ссылка на объяснение (не уверен что рабочий пример) http://webonrails.ru/post/396376462589959881/

Как оказалось, проблема была в css правиле display:none, которое распространялось на внутренние элементы ul, и потому выставлял высоту элемента в 0. И из-за чего скрипт не срабатывал.

Comment: Здравствуйте, но смотрите пробовал на jsfiddle и все ок: https://jsfiddle.net/martynyuk/3u943096/2/

Comment: Ну вариантов может быть много, но мне удалось воспроизвести поведение - https://jsfiddle.net/3u943096/6/ - просто сменил ul[0] на ul . Получается что ошибка кроется в поведении при обращении к ul (ведь именно таким образом оно ведет на вашем сайте).

Comment: Я стучался к элементу напрямую через консоль $(".sidebar__menu-item:first ul.drop")[0].scrollHeight - и получал 0 в ответ. Есть шанс того, что ошибка не в JS, а в стилях - где-то перекрывается стиль и устанавливает высоту 0 независимо от обстоятельств.

Comment: я понял, но вот где этот стиль, уже часа 2 вожусь с этим меню и все безрезультатно

Comment: `.mobile-menu ul {
 position: absolute;
 /* display: none; */
 z-index: 100;
} ` Вот тут я нашел проблему - в коде сайте дисплэй закоментирован, а вот при работе самомго сайта почему то применяется. Когда я его отключил (правило display:none для данного блока) - ul появился как нужно.  (439 строка в main.css - возможно в sass где-то что-то неверно, раз выставляет display:none)

Comment: но если в .mobile-menu ul { position: absolute; /* display: none; */ z-index: 100; } закоментировать  display, то тогда же меню не будет прятаться

Comment: Для начала, он уже закоментирован в css, но работает на сайте (в дебагере он работает). Однако или где то это правило дублируется (в итоге блок остается скрыт). В примере на фидле у тебя самого же вышло так, что блок скрывается под overflow:hidden (его высота ставится в 0 насильно и блока невидно). Просто на сайте ты дополнительно к этому еще повесил правило на display none (еще в 361 строке). Удалять их не нужно - нужно просто правильно их спозиционировать. Я когда убрал (удалил совсем) все display:none  (426 и 361) - то у меня вроде как ничего не поломалось.

Comment: я закоментил две строчки: /*.mobile-menu li ul {
  display: none;
}*/ и .mobile-menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    /*display: none;*/
    z-index: 100;
  } да работает, но теперь меню не прячется в целом, то есть не срабатывает display: none

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44676/discussion-between-alexoander-and-zorro).